# ElasticSearch index getting created but message not coming

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to get Stream message from Kafka and send to ElasticSearch using spark. Spark takes message from kafka in form of df size of various systems and generates messages for different memory usage and push that to ElasticSearch. The problem that i was getting is the index is getting created but the message is not coming in Elastic. I am new to this.

```
package rnd
import com.sun.rowset.internal.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Minutes, Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._
import org.elasticsearch.spark._
object WordFind {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
  }
  import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("KafkaReceiver")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  //val checkpointDir = "/usr/local/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.11.0.2/checkpoint/"
  import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
  import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
  val batchIntervalSeconds = 2
  //val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))
  import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
  import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ReceiverInputDStream
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(batchIntervalSeconds))
  val kafkaStream: ReceiverInputDStream[(String, String)] = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181",
    "spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("wordcounttopic" -> 5))
  import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream
  val filteredStream: DStream[Array[String]] = kafkaStream
    .filter(!_._2.contains("Filesystem")) // eliminate header
    .map(_._2.split("\\s+")) // split with space
  val outputDStream: DStream[String] = filteredStream.map {
    row =>
      val useIdx = row.length - 2
      val useSystemInfo = row.length - 6
      // if Use%>70 for any case> Message: Increase ROM size by 20%
      // if Use%<30% for any case> Message: Decrease ROM size by 25%
      val sysName = row(useSystemInfo).toString
      val usePercent = row(useIdx).replace("%", "").toInt
      usePercent match {
        case x if x > 70 => sysName + " Increase ROM size by 20%"
        case x if x < 30 => sysName + "Decrease ROM size by 25%"
        case _ => "Undefined"
          usePercent.toString

      }
  }
  import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._
  // outputDStream.print()

//outputDStream.print()
  val config: Map[String,String] = Map("es.index.auto.create" -> "yes")
  outputDStream.foreachRDD{messageRDD =>


    //messageRDD.saveToEs("dfvaluemessage_v1/km")
    messageRDD.saveToEs("dfvaluemessage_v1/km", config)
  }
  //outputDStream.foreachRDD{messageRDD =>
    //messageRDD.saveToEs("dfvaluemessage_v1/km")
  //}
  //outputDStream.saveToEs("kafkawordcount_v1/kwc")
  // To make sure data is not deleted by the time we query it interactively
  ssc.remember(Minutes(1))
  //ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDir)
  ssc
  //    }
  // This starts the streaming context in the background.
  ssc.start()
  // This is to ensure that we wait for some time before the background streaming job starts. This will put this cell on hold for 5 times the batchIntervalSeconds.
  ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(batchIntervalSeconds * 5 * 1000)
}
```

ElasticSearch output below:

[image]

Comment: did you see the message printed with `outputDStream.print()`

Comment: Yes. I fixed it. i had to create at dataframe to store. Thank you.

Comment: @s.c. If you have solved the question, then post your answer here (if you think it will be helpful to others). Otherwise you can delete the question.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that I was trying to use foreachRDD and push the messages to Elasticsearch using savetoES. But it can only be done by creating a dataframe. I made that change and it worked fine.

```
package rnd
import com.sun.rowset.internal.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Minutes, Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._
import org.elasticsearch.spark._
object WordFind {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
  }
  import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("KafkaReceiver")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  //val checkpointDir = "/usr/local/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.11.0.2/checkpoint/"
  import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
  import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
  val batchIntervalSeconds = 2
  //val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))
  import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
  import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ReceiverInputDStream
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(batchIntervalSeconds))
  val kafkaStream: ReceiverInputDStream[(String, String)] = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181",
    "spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("wordcounttopic" -> 5))
  import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream
  val filteredStream: DStream[Array[String]] = kafkaStream
    .filter(!_._2.contains("Filesystem")) // eliminate header
    .map(_._2.split("\\s+")) // split with space
  val outputDStream: DStream[String] = filteredStream.map {
    row =>
      val useIdx = row.length - 2
      val useSystemInfo = row.length - 6
      // if Use%>70 for any case> Message: Increase ROM size by 20%
      // if Use%<30% for any case> Message: Decrease ROM size by 25%
      val sysName = row(useSystemInfo).toString
      val usePercent = row(useIdx).replace("%", "").toInt
      usePercent match {
        case x if x > 70 => sysName + " Increase ROM size by 20%"
        case x if x < 30 => sysName + "Decrease ROM size by 25%"
        case _ => "Undefined"
          usePercent.toString

      }
  }
  import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._
  // outputDStream.print()

//outputDStream.print()
  val config: Map[String,String] = Map("es.index.auto.create" -> "yes")
  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
  import sqlContext.implicits._
  outputDStream.foreachRDD{messageRDD =>

val df = messageRDD.toDF("messages")
    //messageRDD.saveToEs("dfvaluemessage_v1/km")
    df.saveToEs("dfvaluemessage_v1/km", config)
  }
  //outputDStream.foreachRDD{messageRDD =>
    //messageRDD.saveToEs("dfvaluemessage_v1/km")
  //}
  //outputDStream.saveToEs("kafkawordcount_v1/kwc")
  // To make sure data is not deleted by the time we query it interactively
  ssc.remember(Minutes(1))
  //ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDir)
  ssc
  //    }
  // This starts the streaming context in the background.
  ssc.start()
  // This is to ensure that we wait for some time before the background streaming job starts. This will put this cell on hold for 5 times the batchIntervalSeconds.
  ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(batchIntervalSeconds * 5 * 1000)
}
```

Comment: To help folks in the future, please add an introductory paragraph to explain what the issue was, and what you changed. There's no need to add "hope this helps" either - that does not actually change how helpful it is, and it could conceivably be added pointlessly to every single question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hey im very new to stack. Sorry about that. Will definitely keep this mind. Thanks

Comment: You can [edit] the post, and add required explanations.

Comment: Yes please to editing. I will flag it for the attention of the Review Queue for now; if it gets deleted, it can still be edited and restored. I believe you can just raise a custom mod flag and ask for it to be undeleted in that situation.

Comment: Edited. Thank you again